# Bootstrap 5.x Tooltips Not Working Inside an AngularJS Controller

Tags: angularjs, tooltip, bootstrap-5

If I may borrow some talk-radio vernacular, "Long time listener; first time caller."

I have been trying for a few days to add some tooltips to my site and really like the look and feel of the Bootstrap 5.3 ones. However, I can not get them to work inside my AngularJS controllers. I did find how to add tooltips with straight AngularJS and/or CSS, but the looks of the results let me underwhelmed compared to the options in Bootstrap 5.3

I can get the Bootstrap 5.3 tooltips to work on a plan HTML page with this code:

```
const tooltipTriggerList = document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]')
const tooltipList = [...tooltipTriggerList].map(tooltipTriggerEl => new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl,{delay: { "show": 1000, "hide": 100 }}))
```

```
<p>Link to <a href="https://www.theguardian.com/us" target="_blank" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" data-bs-title="Hey, it's a tooltip!">The Guardian</a> for tooltip testing.
```

See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/dbqandersons/4q8ubgsr/17/) Fiddle.

I poked around on the web and found how to add tooltips with AngularJS.

```
ToolTipApp.directive('tooltip', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            $(element).hover(function(){
                // on mouseenter
                $(element).tooltip('show');
            }, function(){
                // on mouseleave
                $(element).tooltip('hide');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

```
      <tr ng-repeat="x in records">
        <td>
          <h1>{{x}}</h1>
        </td>
        <td><span style="cursor:pointer" class="badge rounded-pill bg-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hey, it's a tooltip!" tooltip>Edit</span></td>
      </tr>
```

See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/dbqandersons/4bkcdszg/14/) Fiddle.

While it does the job, I'd like to use the Bootstrap 5.3 ones if possible.

However, when I try to marry these two together and use the Bootstrap 5.3 tooltips in my AngularJS controller, they don't work.

This is one of my attempts in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/dbqandersons/50xy3ufn/11/) Fiddle.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?  To use the Bootstrap 5.3 tooltips inside AngularJS controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Bootstrap 5.3, tooltips are initiated by passing the element, so you can pass the element in each directive (you can use `data-bs-*` attributes, or pass them in `options` object):

```
   link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      new bootstrap.Tooltip(element[0], {delay: {"show": 1000, "hide": 100 } });
    
  }
```

demo:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.records = [
    "Photo One",
    "Photo Two",
    "Photo Three",
    "Photo Four",
  ]
});

// ToolTipApp is the ng-app application in your web app
app.directive('tooltip', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      new bootstrap.Tooltip(element[0], {delay: {"show": 1000, "hide": 100 } });
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in records">
      <td>
        <h1>{{x}}</h1>
      </td>
      <td><span style="cursor:pointer" class="badge rounded-pill bg-primary" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Hey, it's a tooltip!" tooltip>Edit</span></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @traynor; works like a champ on my live page.  Been beating my head against the wall on this one for a few days now.

Cheers,

Bill